# Converting dataframe

Tags: r

I have below data frame

```
col1 <- c("A","B", "A")
col2 <- c("C","D","D")
col3 <- c("E","E","E")
col4 <- c("F","F","H")
x <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4)
```

Output of above frame is:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOmUb.jpg)

I want to replace characters to numbers, as below:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksJc3.jpg)

Comment: Depending on your application, you might do better by creating the data frame as factors with the possible character values as levels, then the numeric version, if you need it, is trivial. And often, you *dont* need it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one-liner in base R that works with any number of columns and any names - nothing is hard-coded, so it works with any `x`:

```
> setNames(data.frame(matrix(as.numeric(unlist(x)),ncol=ncol(x))),names(x))
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1    3    5    6
2    2    4    5    6
3    1    4    5    7
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- x %>% 
     unlist %>% 
     as.numeric %>% 
     matrix(ncol=4) %>% 
     data.frame
names(x) <- paste0("col", 1:4)
x

  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1    3    5    6
2    2    4    5    6
3    1    4    5    7
```

Comment: Dont forget to mention which package you use :)

Comment: Thanks. I'd use `dplyr` to do the chaining i.e. `%>%`. It's not a necessity, as you can do each row of command in base, e.g. `x <- unlist(x); x <- as.numeric(x); x <- matrix(x, ncol=4)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with base R:

```
x[] <- match(as.matrix(x), unique(c(as.matrix(x))))
# > x
#   col1 col2 col3 col4
# 1    1    3    5    6
# 2    2    4    5    6
# 3    1    4    5    7
```

Here is a shorter solution:

```
x[] <- as.integer(unlist(x))
```

#### data:

```
x <- data.frame(col1=c("A","B", "A"), col2=c("C","D","D"), col3=c("E","E","E"), col4=c("F","F","H")
```

Comment: User expected a 7 in the last place, since its mapping to the set of letters in the data (so H=7), rather than numerically to the alphabet (H=8)

Comment: Nice and you don't need the outermost parentheses.

Comment: Yes, the parentheses were from playing around with some functions. Now I found a shorter solution.

Comment: Even nicer. Its about 10% faster than my solution according to microbenchmark. The `match` solution is slower!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` from `base R`

```
x[] <- lapply(x, match, LETTERS)
x
#  col1 col2 col3 col4
#1    1    3    5    6
#2    2    4    5    6
#3    1    4    5    8
```